# Java JButton List Call Back

Tags: java, jbutton

I am trying to create a JButton that will call back a selected list of items with the number of the items selected.

I have a primitive list made out displaying different JRadioButtons but with the JRadioButtons named rather than listed out. I have looked on another site that uses Vector collections I believe use the basic for iteration method but I just feel like I am getting a bit overwhelmed.

This is my button code right now.

```
// create new ButtonHandler for button event handling
        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        submitButton.addActionListener( handler );
    } // end Frame constructor

    // inner class for submit button event handler
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {

        //handle button event
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame.this, String.format(
                "You entered: %s", event.getActionCommand() ) );
```

Am I anywhere near the right answer here or am that far off?

Comment: I think it's not clear what you describe, at least for me. If you want the selected items make use of the `Object[] getSelectedValues()` inside your `actionPerformed` method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValues--

Comment: Thanks for the hint I have tried the getSelectedValues() method and the IDE didn't allow me to use it. I am using netbeans 8.0.1 with JDK 7. When I have tried to use that method it gave me a compilation error.

What about my question might I need to show some elaboration?

Comment: It's nice to have you on StackOverflow. In order to help it's vital  to provide the necessary informations. Post the code that you referring to, JList,JRadioButtons etc. Give hints that might help, for example take a picture of the UI and post it. Last but not least,show as the errors that you get.